# How can i get a user's monthly impressions?

Tags: php, pinterest

How can i get a user's monthly view count with php/Pinterest Api?

I want to programmatically get the number of monthly views that appear on any user's Pinterest profile. Is there a url, api address, code block about it?

Comment: Please mentioned whatever code you have tried.

Comment: If I find the address, I'il try the code. However, I do not know the urlyi from which this data was received.

Comment: check here: https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/?

Comment: checked. And nothing. Pinterest Business accounts has monthly impressions. i need this.

Comment: looks like it's not available, another user has same issue check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52705226/pinterest-api-metrics

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Pinterest's [API](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/users/) there is nothing exposed with regards to user Profile views. Therefore, I would assume this is not possible.

Comment: No. Some Pinterest tracking programs can do this.